# Does the Poisson limit theorem talk about random variables or distributions?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

I am confused about the way we take a limit below when saying a Poisson is a limit of binomial, and also whether we are talking about random variables in the limit, or distributions.

The textbook says that the probability distribution of $X$ converges to the Poisson distribution, making me confused as if $n$ grows, we comprehend different random variables with different values of $n$; but this makes it sound as if $n$ grows, we have the same random value $X$ throughout. Here is the passage I am reading:

> Theorem 19.6. Let $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}\left(n, \frac{\lambda}{n}\right)$ where $\lambda>0$ is a fixed constant. Then for every $i=0,1,2, \ldots$,
> $$
> \mathbb{P}[X=i] \longrightarrow \frac{\lambda^i}{i !} e^{-\lambda} \quad \text { as } n \rightarrow \infty .
> $$
> That is, the probability distribution of $X$ converges to the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$.

**My question is, is the following the correct way to view the statement posited above:** for any value $\lambda$, the unique distribution defined by Binomial($n, \frac \lambda n $) where $n$ is any number, approaches the Poisson distribution  Poisson(\lambda) in the sense that we approach the same set of values paired with the same set of probabilities?

I am unsure if the above is the correct way to view this theorem as it didn't mention random variable at all, unlike my textbook, and also I am unsure where I talk about how the set of values assumed by the distribution are the same- as it seems we need a random variable to do this; then we could say that the set of all values which the binomial random variable assumes approaches the set of all values it would assume if it were a Poisson Random variable.  So is this a correct reading of this theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree the notation $X \sim \text{Binomial}(n, \lambda/n)$ can lead to confusion. You could consider a sequence of random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ such that $X_n \sim \text{Binomial}(n, \lambda/n)$. Then for each $i$, you have a sequence of numbers $P(X_1=i),  P(X_2=i), P(X_3=i),\ldots$ and the theorem states what the limit of this sequence is.

More broadly, this is a statement of [convergence in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution), so it is not even necessary to bring random variables into the discussion. The binomial distribution $\text{Binomial}(n, \lambda / n)$ is a distribution on the nonnegative integers (although it gives zero probability to values larger than $n$). Convergence of this sequence of distributions reduces to checking that the probability assigned to each integer $i$ converges to some number.

Comment: +1, though worth noting that convergence in distribution is more generally about pointwise convergence of the cumulative distribution function and it is only particular properties of the support of the binomial and Poisson distributions which allows this be be equivalent to pointwise convergence of the probability mass functions here.